# Checkbox in listview control

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2005, checkbox

Can you have a multicolumn listview control where one of the columns is a checkbox?  Example code or links would be greatly appreciated.

I am using visual studio 2005

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allan Anderson created a custom control to let you do this.
You can find it here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/aa_listview.aspx

Here's some example code for that control:

```
    GlacialList mylist = new GlacialList();

mylist.Columns.Add( "Column1", 100 ); // this can also be added 

         // through the design time support 

mylist.Columns.Add( "Column2", 100 ); 
mylist.Columns.Add( "Column3", 100 ); 
mylist.Columns.Add( "Column4", 100 ); 

GLItem item;

item = this.glacialList1.Items.Add( "Atlanta Braves" );
item.SubItems[1].Text = "8v";
item.SubItems[2].Text = "Live";
item.SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.Bisque;
item.SubItems[3].Text = "MLB.TV"; 

item = this.glacialList1.Items.Add( "Florida Marlins" );
item.SubItems[1].Text = "";
item.SubItems[2].Text = "Delayed";
item.SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
item.SubItems[3].Text = "Audio";


item.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Aqua; // set the background 

      // of this particular subitem ONLY

item.UserObject = myownuserobjecttype; // set a private user object

item.Selected = true; // set this item to selected state

item.SubItems[1].Span = 2; // set this sub item to span 2 spaces


ArrayList selectedItems = mylist.SelectedItems; 
           // get list of selected items
```

Answer (score 26):

Better use grid view control, but if you want **only** one column with checkboxes and that column is the **first** one you can just write:

```
this.listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
```

Comment: Upvoted, although i guess it doesn't have to be the first column;

Answer (score 10):

*Add Checkbox column like below.*

```
myListView.CheckBoxes = true;
myListView.Columns.Add(text, width, alignment);
```

*Add ListViewItem s like below.*

```
ListViewItem lstViewItem = new ListViewItem();
lstViewItem.SubItems.Add("Testing..");
lstViewItem.SubItems.Add("Testing1..");

myListView.Items.Add(lstViewItem);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why dont you try for [XPTable by Mathew Hall](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/XPTable.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a grid view instead, as that gives you more fine control of column contents.

Comment: do you have any examples of this?

Comment: Yeah, something like: myGridDataView.Columns.Add( new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn());

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [ListView.Checkboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can set the the `CheckBoxes` property to `true`. In code this can be done like this:

```
listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [TreeViewAdv](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewadv.aspx). It is open source and hosted on sourceforge.