# How to add CheckBox on beginning of ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on antivirus program and I am having problems with Quarantine.
I added `listView` as showcase of all viruses that are quarantined, but I need help about some things.

I am having trouble when I put checkbox in separate column, I can still resize that column, And I don't want it to be resizable.

I did this for script.
NOTE: **Button click is only temporary for adding item**

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(); // Checkbox 
        lvi.SubItems.Add(""); // Name of virus
        lvi.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Today.ToString()); // Date
        lvi.SubItems.Add(); // Location
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
```

Sorry for duplicated question, I didn't make it clear

Here is image of my idea https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDx8R.jpg

Comment: ListView control has a CheckBoxes property.

Comment: I know, but if I set it in front on separate column, I can still resize that column but I want it to be locked

Comment: But you accepted that answer, so I guess you are ok with that.  You would have to use a DataGridView to get that extra functionality.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I added that as the answer because there is more options on that custom listview. Thanks for help and showing me my fault of duplicating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683/checkbox-in-listview-control). You can set it on the property or in your code

```
this.listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
```