# Creating CheckBox in ListView Column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, checkbox

I am working on Winforms. I want to create checkBox for every row (that means, a column full of checkbox - NOT IN FIRST COLUMN) in ListView.

So far I have seen ListView.CheckBoxes = True, which doesn't fulfill my requirement.

```
 public Replace()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.Columns.Add("", 2);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Sheet",-2,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Replace",-2,HorizontalAlignment.Center);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Create a copy",-2,HorizontalAlignment.Center);
            foreach (var value in Global.ReplaceSheets)
            {
                ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem();
                lvItem.SubItems.Clear();
              //listView1.CheckBoxes = true; makes checkboxes in first column
                lvItem.Checked = true;

                lvItem.SubItems.Add(value.ToString());
                lvItem.SubItems.Add("checkbox");
                lvItem.SubItems.Add("");
                listView1.Items.Add(lvItem);

            }

        }
```

I expect to have control of adding checkbox to any of the column in Winforms.

Comment: Maybe you can use a DataGridView insted of a ListView. The you can add CheckBoxes (or whatever else) in any column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkbox in listview control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683/checkbox-in-listview-control)

Comment: Use `DataGridView` as suggested. Far superior to a `ListView`

Comment: Thanks for response all. @default - Yes I checked this, but the code project reference given in reference again creates checkboxes at first column. at Jimi - Yes you are right. In Datagridview it is possible. Wanted try in listview. Anyway Thanks all again.

Comment: @User1312 [This List View](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4012/C-List-View-v1-3) actually allows you to embed controls to subitems. You can replace progress bars in the example with checkboxes. Just try it, [it works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGXWT.png) Don't just look at pretty pictures. :)